# How redux work when multiple components use parts of complex objects for it's source

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have object (this is one property array and as it is dynamic I can't split it to multiple properties) that I keep in reducer that looks something like this:

```
[
  {type: list, elements: []}
  {type: map, elements: []}
  {type: wheelList, elements: []}
  {type: chart, elements: []}
  {type: dyna, elements: []}
  ...
]
```

In one component I get it from store and access it like:

```
this.props.allElements
```

Then for each of it I render different component (pseudo code):

```
foreach (el in this.props.allElements) {
   if (el == list) {
      return <ListComponent elements={el.elements}>
   }
   if (el == map) {
      return <MapComponent elements={el.elements}>
   }
   ...
}
```

This way each component get only elements that is interested to.
My question is about performance and optimisation.
Is my approach any good?
I suffer some performance issues so checking if maybe my organisation 
here is wrong and need advice if it can be improved.
I have some frequent updates sometimes map can be updated every second.
So if I update only map elements and pass it to action to update it will all this components run render again or just the one that watch map.
**UPDATE**

But to update `map` elements I need to get whole this `object` from `store` in `action update only map` elements and then pass whole updated object to `reducer`.
So only map is changed others are not.
Is react/redux smart enough to update only component that data is changed (map in my case).

Action:

```
export function getScreenElements() : Action {
  return function(dispatch) {
    // get data from server here
    // and do some calculations here
    dispatch({
                type: 'ELEMENTS_RECEIVED',
                allElements: data
            });
```

Reducer:

```
export default function (state:State = initialState, action:Action): State {
  if (action.type === 'ELEMENTS_RECEIVED') {
    return {
      ...state,
      allElements: action.allElements,
    };
```

In big component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  allElements: state.main.allElements
...
class Main extends Component {
...
componentDidMount() {
    // here I actually make a call to get data
}
...
render() {
    return (
       // Here is the big code
       // Loop over props.allElements
       // and render it in different way based on data inside each element
    )
}
```

Data example:

```
[
  {
    "type": "list",
    "count": 99,
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "map",
    "count": 99,
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "test1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "list",
    "count": 99,
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "test1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "list",
    "count": 99,
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "test1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: why aren't you splitting it to different reducers then?

Comment: Will I really get benefit from it? This is object that I get from server and it is very dynamic. That is why I asked for explanation how react will handle situation like this. Will it update only one or all.

Comment: well, i think that doing it in `render` is less preferable then doing this looping inside a `thunk` (action creator) and dispatching each `type` to a different `reducer`.

Comment: Can you give me some direction or example how would you do it in my case? I don't really understand how to split it. Now I loop through all elements and get elements out of it and render it. It's all in one reducer property now. And as I said only map is updating frequently and because of it it renders all over again.

Comment: Ok, post your action and reducer that fetch and pass `this.props.allElements`

Comment: Question updated with what I am doing now. Here as you can see if I update any proeprty of allElements it will re render whole screen.

Answer (score 6):

You can do the loop inside your `thunk` `action` and split the data into seperate `reducers`.

**You Action could look something like this:**

```
// action thunk
export function getScreenElements() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    // get data from server here
    const dataFromServer = fetch('url');
    // do your looping here and dispatch each data acording to its type
    dataFromServer.map(obj => {
      switch (obj.type) {
        case 'list':
          dispatch({
            type: 'LIST_RECEIVED',
            listElements: obj
          });

        case 'map':
          dispatch({
            type: 'MAP_RECEIVED',
            mapElements: obj
          });

        // ....
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Your separate reducers could look something like this:**

```
// map reducer
export default function map(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === 'MAP_RECEIVED') {
    return {
      ...state,
      mapElements: action.mapElements,
    }
  }
}


// list reducer
export default function list(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === 'LIST_RECEIVED') {
    return {
      ...state,
      listElements: action.listElements,
    }
  }
}
```

**And then you can render it like this:**

```
// inside your component render mehtod
render(){
  const { list, map } = this.props; // redux data passed as props from the seperate reducers
  return (
    <div>
      <ListComponent elements={list}>
        <MapComponent elements={map}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> If I put allData to parent and pass allData.xyz to component in render
>   when any data change parent will also reRender as it’s props is
>   changed

Well, there is nothing wrong with Parent being re-rendered. when the `render` method of `component` runs it doesn't mean it will re-render to the physical `DOM`,It will update or override the object of the virtual `DOM` and then will check for differences between the physical and virtual `DOM` via the [Reconciliation and The Diffing Algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) to determine when, how and where should the physical `DOM` get updated.
It can update only certain attributes of `DOM` elements without re-render them, [React Only Updates What’s Necessary](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary).

There is also the option of [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) but i strongly advice against that in your case.

Comment: So this way. If map updates list will not rerender and opposite.

Comment: Yeah, wont re-render if there are no new props or state change internally

Comment: I see the point. But will wait with accepting answer. This solution can’t help me if I get 3 lists and 3 maps in response. Thean each will require different reducers. Or I am wrong somehow and this can be applied to this.

Comment: Its not different than what you are doing now in this asspect. I just moved the logic outside the component to the redux flow. If each object is an array then the data structure of the reducer is an array, and you can map over it as well.

Comment: Sorry, can you update answer with that I will better undertand if I see it. So imagine you have 3 lists here and 1 map. Btw thanks for effort to help :-)

Comment: Post a json example of your data

Comment: I added it to question.

Comment: Do you know in advanced the types you have? I mean do you know that there wheelList, chart, dyna, map and list? Another thing, do need to override the data in your app or add to the existing data? I mean if a new wheelList is fetched from the server will it be added to the existing wheelList in your app or replace it?

Comment: No. It’s dynamic :-(. I am thinking I actally need some implementation wich will allow me to reuse component with redux nut maybe I am wrong. If I put allData to parent and pass allData.xyz to component in render when any data change parent will also reRender as it’s props is changed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with parent re-rendering, react knows how to be explicit with its updating to the `DOM`. if you have not idea what types you can get, for example you can get a new item like `{ type: 'food'}` then i'm afraid you can't avoid using 1 object for all data. if you do know in advanced what types you have then you can go with the approach i mentioned in my answer and maybe just change the reducer data structure from object to array so you could hold multiple items of the same type.

Comment: @1110 do you have any other issues regarding this specific question?

Answer (score 0):

In your data example, there are multiple items with the same type (Ex: list).

This kind of nested objects is not recommended by Redux because you won't be able to optimize your rendering nor optimize the data invalidation.

One way to optimize is to flatten your data in order to look like this:

```
{
  isFetching: false,
  didInvalidate: false,
  data: [
    { type: 'list', id: 1, name: 'test' },
    { type: 'list', id: 2, name: 'test1' },
    { type: 'map', id: 3, name: 'test' },
    { type: 'map', id: 4, name: 'test1' },
    { type: 'list', id: 5, name: 'test' },
    { type: 'list', id: 6, name: 'test1' },
    { type: 'list', id: 7, name: 'test' },
    { type: 'list', id: 8, name: 'test1' },
  ]
}
```

**app.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ListComponent />
        <MapComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**selectors.js**

Use the `reselect` library in order to avoid useless rerender.

This selector is shared because you'll be able to use it for `ListComponent`, `MapComponent` and all your other component to find the items corresponding to your type.

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

export const typeElementsSelector = createSelector(
  state => state.allElements.data,
  (allElements, props) => allElements.find(element => element.type === props.type),
);
```

**ListComponent.js**

The trick here is to only pass the element `id` and let the children check when to rerender.

Note that `ListComponent` will rerender **only and only if** there is any modification in the `listElements` value.
Examples:

- There is now a new item of a type 'list'
- There is one removed item of type 'list'
- One of the current 'list' item were modified

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

import { typeElementsSelector } from './selectors';

class ListComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.listElements.length) return (<div>Empty</div>);

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.listElements.length} list elements</h2>
        <div>
          {this.props.listElements.map(element => (
            <ListComponentItem key={`list-${element.id}`} id={element.id} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (reducers, props) => ({
  listElements: typeElementsSelector(reducers, props),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListComponent);
```

**ListComponentItem.js**

You can now display whatever you what you want.
The component will rerender **only and only if** this item in the reducer has been modified

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

class ListComponentItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.name}</div>
  }
}

const elementSelector = createSelector(
  state => state.allElements.data,
  (allElements, props) => allElements.find(element => element.id === props.id),
);

const mapStateToProps = (reducers, props) => ({
  element: elementSelector(reducers, props),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListComponentItem);
```

The other way is to create a reducer for each type and use the same logic as above.

```
{
  listElements: {
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false,
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: 'test' },
      { id: 2, name: 'test1' },
      { id: 5, name: 'test' },
      { id: 6, name: 'test1' },
      { id: 7, name: 'test' },
      { id: 8, name: 'test1' },
    ]
  },
  mapElements: {
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false,
    data: [
      { id: 3, name: 'test' },
      { id: 4, name: 'test1' },
    ]
  },
}
```

Remember that your API might send you data formatted in a kind of way but you can reformat them as you desire.

**An interesting article talking about this kind of optimization:** https://medium.com/dailyjs/react-is-slow-react-is-fast-optimizing-react-apps-in-practice-394176a11fba

**If you want to go further with data normalization best practices in redux:** https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Hope it helps.